# Placeholder not working mozilla latest with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less, placeholder

Bootstrap v2.3.1 - **less**  placeholder styles working on chrome but not working on Mozilla latest version

Please help 
Less code here

```
.placeholder(red);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mozilla Updated Syntax

In the [version 19.0 release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/19.0/releasenotes/buglist.html), it states it changed the `-moz-placeholder` from being a pseudoclass (`:-moz-placeholder`) to a pseudoelement (`::-moz-placeholder`, *note the double colons*) which was [implementing this bug fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737786). Apparently it was not made backwards compatible, because [**the double-colon syntax works in this fiddle but the single colon syntax does not**](http://jsfiddle.net/VsfFY/).

However, Bootstrap at present (6-6-2013) has the pseudoclass (single colon) version [in its mixin](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less) (line 83 as of this writing). So you need to either go in an manually fix the `mixins.less` file of bootstrap to correct it to the new syntax  (not my first choice), or create your own override mixin to also add the new syntax, like so (better choice):

```
.placeholder(@color: @placeholderText) {
  &::-moz-placeholder {
    color: @color;
  }
}
```

[Once bootstrap is updated to version 3](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7052), then you can get rid of your override mixin.

Comment: Did bootstrap fix the issue ? Can i update with new version ?

Comment: I doubt it's been updated, since I just pulled the info from it yesterday. They may not even be aware there is an issue.

Comment: Some investigating found [this issue which indicates it is fixed for version 3](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7052) (of course, bootstrap is on 2.3.2 at present). So the next release should address it.

Answer (score 1):

change mixins file

```
// Placeholder text
// -------------------------
.placeholder(@color: @placeholderText) {
&:-moz-placeholder {
color: @color;
}
&:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: @color;
}
&::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: @color;
}

&::-moz-placeholder { // this for latest mozilla
    color: @color;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
 }
 ::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
 }
 :-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
 }
 :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
 }
 <style>
<input type="email" placeholder="anytext">
```